# What are some good techniques (tips and tricks) to practice Melodic and Rhythmic dictation that isn't really basic?

Tags: theory, rhythm, ear-training, transcription

I find that a lot of the techniques I use to practice melodic and rhythmic dictation are good but often stay at a really basic level. I want to get better at it but it's hard to stay focused when you have to wade through all the simple 3 note melodies etc.

Are there some good tips and tricks how I can improve my skill of notating dictated music?

Comment: What tools are you currently using?

Comment: There are endless numbers of songs out there. If you like a particular style or even a handful of artist there are still many many songs. Use those. Song too easy? Pick a different one. Too hard? Pick a different one. Want to focus on rhythm? notate the rhythm. Want to focus on melody? Notate the melody.

Comment: Just by changing "tools" to "techniques" makes this a suitable question.

Comment: This is still rather broad. We don't typically answer "tips and tricks" for that reason.